# Dynamic "Add to Cart" PayPal buttons for selling Prints on Website

Tags: button, joomla, paypal, shopping-cart

Not sure if this is the best place to ask, but thought I'd give it a try.

I'm potentially taking on a site for a friend.

She has a Gallery of Images that she has taken and would like to sell prints of these on her web site at different sizes (A4, A3) using PayPal.

It's currently powered by Joomla.

Can someone explain how I would do this using PayPal?

I've only ever created specific buttons for items in PayPal.

Many thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to go with a real e-commerce solution, i.e. some kind of shop where the user can choose a version of a product (in your case the size of the image).

You will some more work to get it setup the way you like, but the advantage is that running/updating/scaling the product range will only require minimum effort.

My advise is to go with a e-commerce extension that is not too powerful and complicated, I can recommend for example the [SimpleCaddy](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/e-commerce/shopping-cart/4148). But there are of course [other options](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/e-commerce/shopping-cart).